# Why is Common Table Expression called "Common"?

Tags: sql

Why does CTE have the word common?

Comment: I imagine because you can reference it more than once without needing to repeat the definition. E.g. `WITH CTE AS (SELECT ...) SELECT * FROM CTE C1 JOIN CTE C2...`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm pretty sure the "common" refers to the fact that the alias is available anywhere in the query. Think of it as meaning "common expression for a query that happens to be table." I can imagine discussions over words like "global" and "local" for this beast, with "common" being some sort of consensus.

To understand the idea, you need to understand the scoping of table aliases for subqueries. These are limited in scope to the query containing the reference and to subqueries. Of course, CTEs were introduced before lateral joins. At that time, there was no way to share "common" expressions across different subqueries in a join.

They have been around for a long time.